# Pass parameterization to an util function

Tags: python, pytest

I am fairly new to pytest. I have a util function which makes all the API calls for all the test cases, which is something like this

```
def post_graphql_request(query, variable=None):
   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'access_token': get_access_token()}
   response = requests.post(api_url + '/query', headers=headers, json={'query': query, 'variables': variable})
   return response.text
```

get_access_token() is a function that returns the access token for a user account. Here is an example of a test case.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def my_fixture():
   post_graphql_request(query, variables)
   return abc

def test_func(my_fixture):
   test = my_fixture['abc']
   post_graphql_request(query, variables(test))
   assert abc
```

Now I am trying to run the tests for multiple user persona, ex: user A and user B. The only difference between the two users are difference in access token, which in turns determines the user access level. I am planning to run my tests for both the personas. I tried to parametrize the test function, I have to make that change to all the test cases/classes and I have some fixtures that use the same util function to make the call, I need to update that as well. I am wondering if there is a better way to just make the change at the util function level to run the request twice - one for user A and other for user B. I tried some approaches like parametrizing the `post_graphql_request` but then the code is expecting all the test to pass the value for the parameterized argument. Please share your thoughts on the same.